# Querying Wikipedia API sometimes causes html to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

Currently attempting to build a Wikipedia viewer as per the Free Code Camp project. You can see the whole CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/elemkeh/pen/eBKQpW). Now, in my console I can see that sometimes, I get a response with the data I was looking for. Other times, I get no response at all, and still other times running the search causes all of the content on my page to simply disappear. I thought initially it might be a caching issue, but there are instances where it will successfully run multiple searches in a row then either stop or disappear; and others where it will not receive any data at all.

When I have these malfunctions, the console does not display any errors, so I don't have any feedback about what's going wrong.

Here's the relevant code:

```
function wikiSrch(){

  var srchParam = "";
  var srchRes;

  $("#searchB").click(function(){
    srchParam = $("#inpt").val();

    $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + srchParam + "&format=json&callback=?", function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  });


}



$(document).ready(function(){
  wikiSrch();
})
```

Comment: Im unable to recreate with code here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLdQmQ - your codepen link does not contain any code...

Comment: Your button doesn't have `type="button"`, so it defaults to `type="submit"`. So it's submitting the form and reloading the page.

Comment: @Barmar That seems to have fixed the issue! Thank you.